# Turn values in a DataFrame column into column labels

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

My data frame looks like this:

```
Date    Time    Sensors Status
123 4/3/2008    24:08.1 M024    1
125 4/3/2008    24:11.8 M024    1
127 4/3/2008    24:13.6 M025    1
129 4/3/2008    24:14.0 M024    1
```

and I would want my dataframe to look like:

```
Date    Time              M024 M025 
123 4/3/2008    24:08.1    1
125 4/3/2008    24:11.8    1
127 4/3/2008    24:13.6         1
129 4/3/2008    24:14.0
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried pivots: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

Comment: Thanks for your replies:  I have used this and seemed to work although i still have problem with the aggfunc :                              result.pivot_table(index="Time", columns="Sensors", values="Status", 
    aggfunc=sum).fillna(0)                                                                                                       duplicates are summed which is what i dont want to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df

         Date     Time Sensor  Status
123  4/3/2008  24:08.1   M024       1
125  4/3/2008  24:11.8   M024       1
127  4/3/2008  24:13.6   M025       1
129  4/3/2008  24:14.0   M024       1


print df.pivot_table(index=['Date','Time'], columns='Sensor', values='Status', fill_value='')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index()

       Date     Time M024 M025
0  4/3/2008  24:08.1    1     
1  4/3/2008  24:11.8    1     
2  4/3/2008  24:13.6         1
3  4/3/2008  24:14.0    1
```

EDIT:

I think you need convert column `Status` to `int` or `float`, because it seems is not numeric (although looks like numeric):

```
df['Status'] = df['Status'].astype(int)

df['Status'] = df['Status'].astype(float)
```

If values are duplicated, then are agregated by function in parameter `aggfunc`. Default function is `np.mean`:

```
print df
         Date     Time Sensor  Status
123  4/3/2008  24:08.1   M024       2
123  4/3/2008  24:08.1   M024       1
125  4/3/2008  24:11.8   M024       1
127  4/3/2008  24:13.6   M025       3
129  4/3/2008  24:14.0   M024       1

print df.pivot_table(index=['Date','Time'], 
                     columns='Sensor', 
                     values='Status', 
                     fill_value='',
                     aggfunc=np.mean).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()

       Date     Time M024 M025
0  4/3/2008  24:08.1  1.5     
1  4/3/2008  24:11.8    1     
2  4/3/2008  24:13.6         3
3  4/3/2008  24:14.0    1
```

Is possible it change, e.g. to `sum` -  `aggfunc=sum`:

```
print df.pivot_table(index=['Date','Time'], 
                     columns='Sensor', 
                     values='Status', 
                     fill_value='',
                     aggfunc=sum).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()

       Date     Time M024 M025
0  4/3/2008  24:08.1    3     
1  4/3/2008  24:11.8    1     
2  4/3/2008  24:13.6         3
3  4/3/2008  24:14.0    1
```

EDIT1:

Check all [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) values by columns `Date`, `Time` and `Sensor` is possible by:

```
print df[df.duplicated(subset=['Date', 'Time', 'Sensor'], keep=False)]
```

If values in column `Status` are same, you can [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) before pivoting:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date', 'Time', 'Sensor'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply: i got this error when i tried using pivot table:              Data Error: No numeric types to aggregate ,                        is it due to fill_value?

Comment: No, I thint it is problem, that column `Status` is not numeric. Try function `astype`. Btw, I add another 2 samples with demonstrating aggregating function. Please check it.

Comment: yeah i have converted "on,off" states to 1 and 0 and i dont want to use the aggfunc, is there any other way without using aggfunc?

Comment: Is possible in same time, same sensor have different `Status`? You can check it by `print df[df.duplicated(subset=['Date', 'Time', 'Sensor'], keep=False)]`

Comment: Thanks , i have got these 4 entries when the status remains the same,although i will need to keep these as well:                                       Date Time Sensors Status
827 4/3/2008 56:44.1 M013 1
859 4/3/2008 9:57:40 L010 1
860 4/3/2008 9:57:40 L010 1
864 4/3/2008 9:57:42 L008 1
865 4/3/2008 9:57:42 L008 1
828 4/3/2008 56:44.1 M013 0

Comment: @Kira - it is problem. It is not possiblenot  aggregating. I think problem is you cannot process different `Status` in same `Time` `827 4/3/2008 56:44.1 M013 1` and `828 4/3/2008 56:44.1 M013 0`. What is then output? `1` or `0`? I think it is maybe problem with accuracy of time. One possible solution is use `aggfunc='first'` - return only [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) value, if duplicates.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael, will try that out

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is

#### Solution

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)  # just to make sure
df.set_index(['Date', 'Time', 'Sensor', 'Status'], inplace=True)

# this should take care of duplicate sensors
df = df.sort_index().groupby(level=2).last()

df = df.unstack()
```

I'd leave it here but to answer your question, we'll take one more step

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when i tried i get the follwoing error:Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: That's because your sensor names are not unique within the column. What do you want to do with duplicates? Sum the statuses?  Take most recent?

Comment: Yeah i will need all the data in the column, can't ignore any sensor status, i have converted "on,off" states to "1,0" respectively, so i need to keep when a motion sensor was on and off during the recorded time